# Non-blocking client FTP retrieval and write

Tags: python, twisted

I am building an FTP test server and client with Twisted.  The server runs great.  It is basically the same from the Twisted ftpserver.py example.  The client is where I am having some blocking issues during my file retrieval and writing.  I have tried to resolve it through some quick Twisted threading utilities, but to no avail.

Here is my server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import print_function, division, absolute_import

# Import twisted things

from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPFactory
from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPRealm
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import AllowAnonymousAccess

p = Portal(FTPRealm("test/"), [AllowAnonymousAccess()])

f = FTPFactory(p)
f.timeOut = None

reactor.listenTCP(5504, f)
reactor.run()
```

The client side, paired with this, is a simple wxPython GUI that presents a text box to write the name of the file you want to retrieve in.  Within this GUI there is a `wx.Timer` that executes a method every 50 milliseconds.  This is what is blocking my FTP file retrieval.  I find that because the main thread is being used up, the protocol that receives the data is having hiccups.  If you are wondering why I have this setup I am simulating the use case for a much larger project.

My attempt to solve this has been to use `deferToThread` on the specific point when I need to retrieve a file.  However, by printing the current thread I find that the protocol that is receiving the data is running in the main thread.  This is the problem I am trying to solve.  Any help is much appreciated.

My client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import  print_function, division, absolute_import

import wx
import sys
import threading

from twisted.internet import wxreactor
wxreactor.install()

from twisted.internet import reactor

from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPClient

from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import threads
from twisted.python import log

# This is the GUI
class TextSend(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Request Files", size=(200, 75))

        self.protocol = None # ftp client protocol
        self.factory = None

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vertSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        horzSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.fileName = None
        self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(parent=panel, id=100, size=(100,-1))
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Retr.")

        # timer and checkbox for timer
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.check = wx.CheckBox(parent=panel, label="Start blocking")

        #Bind
        self.textbox.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.getText)
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.press)
        self.check.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onCheck)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer, self.timer)

        horzSizer.Add(self.textbox, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        horzSizer.Add(self.btn, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        vertSizer.Add(horzSizer, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vertSizer.Add(self.check, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        panel.SetSizer(vertSizer)
        panel.Layout()

    def getText(self, evt):
        self.fileName = str(self.textbox.GetValue())

    def onCheck(self, evt):
        yes = self.check.GetValue()
        if yes:
            print("Starting timer")
            self.timer.Start(50)
        else: # no
            self.timer.Stop()

    def onTimer(self, evt):
        #print("Triggered timer")
        pass

    def press(self, evt):
        print("Send:", self.fileName)

        d = threads.deferToThread(self.retrieve)
        d.addCallback(self.done)

    def retrieve(self):
        print(threading.current_thread())
        # This is what does the retrieving.  Pass in FileWriter and
        # FileWriter's dataReceived method is called by main thread
        self.protocol.retrieveFile(self.fileName, FileWriter(self.fileName), offset=0).addCallbacks(self.done, self.fail)
        return "Done with deferToThread"

    def done(self, msg):
        print(threading.current_thread())
        print("DONE Retrieving:", msg)

    def fail(self, error):
        print('Failed. Error was:')
        print(error)

# This writes to the file of a same name as the one retrieved.
class FileWriter(protocol.Protocol):

    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.f = open(fileName, 'wb')
        print("FROM FileWriter __init__:", threading.current_thread())

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print("Byte size", len(data))
        print("FROM FileWriter dataReceived:", threading.current_thread())
        self.f.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print("Writing closed and done")
        print("FROM FileWriter connectionLost:", threading.current_thread())
        self.f.close()

# Client FTP Protocol
class TestClient(FTPClient, object):

    def __init__(self, factory, username, password, passive):
        super(TestClient, self).__init__(username=username, password=password, passive=passive)
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        print("hello")
        gui = self.factory.gui
        gui.protocol = self

# Twisted Client Factory
class FileClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):

    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.gui = gui
        self.protocol = None

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        user = 'anonymous'
        passwd = 'twisted@matrix.com'
        self.protocol = TestClient(self, username=user, password=passwd, passive=1)
        return self.protocol

    def clientConnectionLost(self, transport, reason):
        print("Connectiong lost normally:", reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, transport, reason):
        print("Connection failed:", reason)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize and show GUI
    logger = log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    app = wx.App(False)
    app.frame = TextSend()
    app.frame.Show()
    reactor.registerWxApp(app)

    # Build Factory
    f = FileClientFactory(app.frame)

    # Connect to FTP server
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 5504, f)
    reactor.run()

    wxPython main loop.
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `deferToThread(function_that_uses_twisted_apis)`.  Twisted APIs are almost all non-thread-safe.  You must use them in the reactor thread only (the exceptions are a couple thread-scheduling-related APIs).

Instead, get rid of your blocking code.  Put *it* into another thread, another process, or rewrite it to be non-blocking.

Comment: I will try this approach then.